# PhpMygraph - How assign array from database mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code :

```
 <?php    
    //Set content-type header
    header("Content-type: image/png");

    //Include phpMyGraph5.0.php
    include_once('phpMyGraph5.0.php');
    include("koneksi.php");

    //Set config directives
    $cfg['title'] = 'Example graph';
    $cfg['width'] = 500;
    $cfg['height'] = 250;


    //Set data
    $query="select col1, col2 from tab1 where sub_project = 'sometext'";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $data = array(
        $row['col1'] => $row['col2'],
    );

    //Create phpMyGraph instance
    $graph = new phpMyGraph();

    //Parse
    $graph->parseVerticalColumnGraph($data, $cfg);
?>
```

In my case, the data in `col1` is a text, and in `col2` is a number.
but with that code, the graph it shows just the first row value.
meanwhile the value from database is more than one value.

Comment: thanks for your reply j0k, did you mean like Jahanzeb answer?

Answer (score 0):

Add your fetched result in while loop, like this.

```
<?php    
    //Set content-type header
    header("Content-type: image/png");

    //Include phpMyGraph5.0.php
    include_once('phpMyGraph5.0.php');
    include("koneksi.php");

    //Set config directives
    $cfg['title'] = 'Example graph';
    $cfg['width'] = 500;
    $cfg['height'] = 250;


    //Set data
    $query="select col1, col2 from tab1 where sub_project = 'sometext'";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
       $data[$row['col1']] = $row['col2'];
    }

    //Create phpMyGraph instance
    $graph = new phpMyGraph();

    //Parse
    $graph->parseVerticalColumnGraph($data, $cfg);
?>
```

And `$data` is multiarray, and have all records from DB

Hope this code will help you

Comment: Thankyou for your reply Jahanzeb, if i use this code _$data[] = array($row['col1'] => $row['col2']_  the result says that the value is not numeric, but if if i add "[]" at _$graph->parseVerticalColumnGraph($data[], $cfg);_ there is no error, but didn't give me the result either...

Comment: @loeds Ok, I got it. According to the example here https://github.com/xpandgithub/Virtual-Career-Network-1.09/blob/master/careerladder/graph.php I just made a change in while loop. I changed the `$data` array to `$data[$row['col1']] = $row['col2'];`. Hope it will work.